# Add action to terminate application event

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Could you tell me if there is any possibility to add own function to terminate application event. I want to send some information to logs always when user click button on his phone.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation for `applicationDidEnterBackground:` in the `UIApplicationDelegate` class description.  (Since iOS 4, the default behavior when the button is pressed is not termination...though your app may choose differently.)

Answer (score 1):

You can call your own method from `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`

Check out developer documentation for detailed info - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

One point to not here as mention in docs -

"Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return."